# How to find the containing class of a decorated method in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a decorator class which would decorate methods in other classes. However, I need the class which holds the decorated method available in the decorator. I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Here's an example:

```
class my_decorator(object):

  def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
    print(self.__class__.__name__ + ".__init__")
    self.arg1 = arg1
    self.arg2 = arg2

  def __call__(self, my_callable):
    print(self.__class__.__name__ + ".__call__")
    print(type(my_callable))
    self.my_callable = my_callable
#    self.my_callable_method_class = ?where to get this?

    def function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      print(self.__class__.__name__ + ".function_wrapper")
      print(self.arg1)
      self.my_callable.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
      print(self.arg2)

    return function_wrapper


class MyClass(object):

  @my_decorator(arg1="one", arg2="two")
  def decorated_method(self):
    print(self.__class__.__name__ + ".decorated_method")
    print(type(self.decorated_method))
    print("hello")


m = MyClass()
m.decorated_method()
```

That will print out this:

```
my_decorator.__init__
my_decorator.__call__
<type 'function'>
my_decorator.function_wrapper
one
MyClass.decorated_method
<type 'instancemethod'>
hello
two
```

In the decorator class the callable is of type function, while inside the class itself it is of type instancemethod. I can get the im_class from instancemethod, but there is no such thing in function.

How can I get the class containing the decorated method from within the decorator?

I could do this:

```
class my_decorator(object):

  def __init__(self, cls, arg1, arg2):

.
.

class MyClass(object):

  @my_decorator(cls=MyClass, arg1="one", arg2="two")
  def decorated_method(self):

.
.
```

But I would not like to do that because it's redundant and not nice.

Or should I implement this some other way? I basicly need a couple of arguments to the decorator, and I need the class of the decorated method in the decorator.

Comment: When exactly do you need the class? You may modify the internal wrapper to `def function_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)` and obtain the class as `self.__class__`. If you need the class outside the decorator then its a lot harder as katrielalex already pointed out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could decorate the *class*:

```
@decorate
class MyClass(object):

  @my_decorator(arg1="one", arg2="two")
  def decorated_method(self):
```

and use the outer decorator to send the class argument to the inner.

---

None of your proposals can work, because they require access to the class *before it exists*. When you define a class, you first execute the code inside its body (defining functions etc) and then assign the resulting scope to the class as its `__dict__`. So at the time that `decorated_method` is defined, `MyClass` doesn't exist yet.

Comment: This looks like the way to go. But how do I link the class decorator and the method decorator? I will have lots of classes and methods using the same decorators...

Comment: `@my_decorator` should mark the methods that it has decorated, say by giving them a special attribute. `@decorate` should iterate over all the class methods, filtering those without the special attribute, and perform its decoration on each in turn.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a revised version which works.

```
# This holds all called method_decorators
global_method_decorator_list = []

class class_decorator(object):
  def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
    print(self.__class__.__name__ + ".__init__")
    self.arg1 = arg1
    self.arg2 = arg2

  def __call__(self, my_class):
    print(self.__class__.__name__ + ".__call__")
    print(repr(my_class))
    print(my_class.__name__)
    self.cls = my_class
    class_decorators[my_class] = self
    self.my_class = my_class

    # Call each method decorator's second_init()
    for d in global_method_decorator_list:
      d._method_decorator_.second_init(self, my_class)

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      print(self.__class__.__name__ + ".wrapper")
      print(self.arg1)
      retval = self.my_class.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
      print(self.arg2)
      return retval

    return wrapper


class method_decorator(object):
  def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
    print(self.__class__.__name__ + ".__init__")
    self.arg1 = arg1
    self.arg2 = arg2

  def __call__(self, my_callable):
    print(self.__class__.__name__ + ".__call__")
    print(repr(my_callable))
    self.my_callable = my_callable

    # Mark the callable and add to global list
    my_callable._method_decorator_ = self
    global_method_decorator_list.append(my_callable)

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      print(self.__class__.__name__ + ".wrapper")
      print(self.arg1)
      retval=self.my_callable.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
      print(self.arg2)
      return retval

    return wrapper

  def second_init(self, the_class_decorator, the_class):
    print(self.__class__.__name__ + ".second_init")
    print("The Class: " + repr(the_class))**


@class_decorator(arg1="One", arg2="Two")
class MyClass(object):

  @method_decorator(arg1="one", arg2="two")
  def decorated_method(self):
    print(self.__class__.__name__ + ".decorated_method")
    print(type(self.decorated_method))
    print("hello")


m = MyClass()
m.decorated_method()
```

The output looks like this:

```
class_decorator.__init__
method_decorator.__init__
method_decorator.__call__
<function decorated_method at 0x3063500>
class_decorator.__call__
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
MyClass
method_decorator.second_init
The Class: <class '__main__.MyClass'>
class_decorator.wrapper
One
Two
method_decorator.wrapper
one
MyClass.decorated_method
<type 'instancemethod'>
hello
two
```

The difference is that there is now a separate decorator for the class. The class decorator's **call**() will call each of the method decorators "second_init()" method, and passes the class there.

It is interesting to note, that the method_decorator's **call**() will be called before the class_decorator's.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the object returned by your decorator a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html), then you can hook the attribute lookup to return some other object that links the method and class (or instance).

For a method style descriptor, you only need to implement the `__get__` method.  When looking up the method on the class, the following two are equivalent:

```
m = MyClass.decorated_method
# It will actually get the object from any parent class too.  But this will do for a simple example
m = MyClass.__dict__['decorated_method'].__get__(MyClass)
```

And for instances, the following are equivalent:

```
instance = MyClass()
m = instance.decorated_method
m = type(instance).__dict__['decorated_method'].__get__(instance, type(instance))
```

So the expression `instance.decorated_method(...)` actually calls the object returned by your `__get__` method.  This is the same process that allows simple function objects to turn into bound method objects that add the implicit `self` argument.

When creating this callable, you should have all the information you need.

Comment: The problem with this one is that I need to do work with the class before I create the first instance.

Comment: Fair enough.  Then you'll probably want a decorator that marks functions like katrielalex suggested, and then fix things up either from a class decorator or a metaclass constructor.